# Recursive function call for menu in partial view

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, c#-10.0

I have a nested data object for a set of items within menus. Each menu has multiple sub-menus and it also has multiple sub-child menus. there is no set limit to the depth of sub-menus. I have two classes.MenuItemList class declares some properties And inherits MenuItemList class. MainMenu class has only the same type of list. It looks something like this:

MainMenu class:

```
public class MainMenu : MenuItemList
{
    public List<MainMenu> MenuList { get; set; }
}
```

Another MenuItemList Class:

```
 public class MenuItemList
{
    public String MainMenuText { get; set; }
    public String Controller { get; set; }
    public String Action { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[Area("Panel")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MenuModel();
        model.MainMenuList();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Another MenuModel Class that use in the controller

```
public class MenuModel
{
    public MenuModel()
    {
    }
    public List<MainMenu> MainMenuList()
    {
        List<MainMenu> MainMenuList = new List<MainMenu>();

        MainMenuList.Add(new MainMenu
        {
            Action = "Index",
            Controller = "Test",
            MainMenuText = "MainMenu",
            MenuList = new List<MainMenu>() 
            {
                new MainMenu()
                {
                    Action = "Index",
                    Controller = "Test",
                    MainMenuText = "SubMenu",
                    MenuList = new List<MainMenu>()
                    {
                        new MainMenu()
                        {
                            Action = "Index",
                            Controller = "Test",
                            MainMenuText = "SubChildMenu",
                            MenuList = new List<MainMenu>()
                            {
                                new MainMenu()
                                {
                                    Action = "Index",
                                    Controller = "Test",
                                    MainMenuText = "SubChildSubMenu"
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                },
                new MainMenu()
                {
                    Action = "Index",
                    Controller = "Test",
                    MainMenuText = "SubMenu"
                } 
            }
        });

        var menu = new MainMenu();
        menu.MenuList = MainMenuList;

        return MainMenuList;
    }
}
```

But I could not write it on the view page.

Someone help me, please.

Comment: Do you want a data display like this, for example: Menu 1 contains a menu 2, and menu 2 contains a menu 3, and then you need to display this level of data on the page, is that right?

Comment: Yes I want to display dynamic menu